# Catel authentication + MahApps

Tags: c#, authentication, mahapps.metro, catel, orchestra

I am currently learning Catel+Orchestra using MahApps Metro.
I am doing the Authentication example from the Catel.Examples project using the MetroUI.
My problem is when i create a new MainWindow in my MahAppsService

```
        public FrameworkElement GetMainView()
    {
        return new MainWindow();
    }
```

The constructor of the MainWindowViewModel is never called

```
public MainWindowViewModel(UIVisualizerService uiVisualizarService, IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider)
    {
        _uiVisualizerService = uiVisualizarService;
        _authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        RoleCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] { "Read-Only", "Administrator" });
        ShowView = new Command(OnShowViewExecute, OnShowViewCanExecute, "ShowView");
    }
```

I have narrowed it down to the 2 dependencies of the constructor. If i remove the UIVisualizerService and IAuthenticacionProvider dependencies the constructor is properly called but the ModelView needs those two services later on.

I am lost at what can i do to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a explicit injection of the viewmodel into the mainwindow constructor.

```
public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel _mainwindowviewmodel):base(_mainwindowviewmodel)
 {
 InitializeComponent();
 }
```

Declaring the field for the AuthenticationProvider interface to the MahAppsService class.

```
private readonly IAuthenticationProvider _authenticationProvider;
```

Also adding the dependency of the AuthenticationProvider interface to the constructor.

```
 public MahAppsService(ICommandManager commandManager, IMessageService messageService, IUIVisualizerService uiVisualizerService, IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvicer)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => commandManager);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => messageService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => uiVisualizerService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => authenticationProvicer);
        _commandManager = commandManager;
        _messageService = messageService;
        _uiVisualizerService = uiVisualizerService;
        _authenticationProvider = authenticationProvicer;
    }
```

And the last step is creating an instance of the viewmodel in the GetMainView in the MahAppsService class.

```
 public FrameworkElement GetMainView()
 {
 var mainwindowViewModel = TypeFactory.Default.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion<MainWindowView‌​Model>(_uiVisualizerService, _authenticationProvider);
 return new MainWindow(mainwindowViewModel);
 }
```

Please note that this might not be the best way to do it but it gets the work done. If someone has better way feel free to share it.

Answer (score 1):

You must register the IAuthenticationProvider in the ServiceLocator:

```
var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;

serviceLocator.RegisterType<IAuthenticationProvider, MyAuthenticationProvider>();
```

Note that all services inside Catel are automatically registered for you, but you must register your own services yourself (for example, by using [ModuleInit](https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit) or another entry point in your assembly).

Comment: I already registered the custom service on the startup of the app.  


`public partial class App : Application  
 {  
     protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)  
     {  
         var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;  
         serviceLocator.RegisterType<IMahAppsService, MahAppsService>();  
         serviceLocator.RegisterType<IAuthenticationProvider, Authentication.AuthenticationProvider>();  
...`

Comment: async void for OnStartup? I recommend not doing that since you have no control about the flow (you should *only* use async void on event handlers that are not async). Can you upload a repro?

Comment: You are right on the async and i made the proper changes.

Comment: I solved the problem adding a explicit injection of the viewmodel into the mainwindow constructor.
`public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel  
_mainwindowviewmodel):base(_mainwindowviewmodel)  
{  
InitializeComponent();  }`
Then creating an instance of the viewmodel in the GetMainView in MahAppsService
`public FrameworkElement GetMainView()
{  
var mainwindowViewModel = 
TypeFactory.Default.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion<MainWindowViewModel>(_uiVisualizerService, _authenticationProvider);
return new MainWindow(mainwindowViewModel);
}`
 Not sure this is the proper way to solve it.

Comment: Uploaded the 'solved' version to a repo in github. Feel free to look at it.
https://github.com/venomAA/CatelAuthenticationExample

Comment: Glad you have it solved. You can always enable logging (LogManager.AddDebugLogListener(false)) to check if Catel shows you warnings / errors.

Comment: Thank you Gert for the tips and for the fast answers.